# The ? boolean zen operator

Tags: java, boolean, boolean-operations

I've never used the `?` operator before and I'm trying to figure out how it works.

I have been reading countless pages and decided to try for myself.

I have the following statement:

```
 getSelection().equalsIgnoreCase("Måned") ? calendarView.currentlyViewing.set(Calendar.Year) : showPopup();
```

As far as I can understand, if the left hand side (boolean) is true it will set my calendarView.to year and if not (getSelection is not equal to måned) it will call the method `showPopup()`.

But when I type this into Eclipse I get a syntax error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The suggested usage is this: `$name = isGirl()? 'Lauren' : 'Bob'`

Comment: It's difficult to tell without an error message but my guess is that both these methods have a `void` return type. That's not how `?:` works, both statements on the RHS of `?` should evaluate to a non-void value.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're trying to use the [conditional `? :` operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) to decide which *statement* to execute. That's not its intention. The conditional operator can't be used as a statement - it's only to choose which *expression* to use as the overall result.

So this is fine:

```
foo(condition ? nonVoidMethod1() : nonVoidMethod2());
```

but this isn't:

```
condition ? voidMethod1() : voidMethod2();
```

You should just use an `if` statement here:

```
if (getSelection().equalsIgnoreCase("Måned")) {
    calendarView.currentlyViewing.set(Calendar.Year);
} else {
    showPopup();
}
```

Comment: Thank you i understand it now :P so the left hand side is a condition and then the right hand side decides what the variable needs to be